# How to extract result from the fastest responding thread from a group of threads?

Tags: rx-java, observable

Problem : Consider a scenario where there are multiple services that can perform a particular task. Each service can respond to the task with varying amounts of time. We need to always pick the response from the fastest performing service.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you right, you need something like this:

```
taskSource
    .flatMap(task -> // for each task
        Observable.merge(
            // submit same task to multiple services
            service1.submit(task),
            service2.submit(task),
            ...,
            serviceN.submit(task)
            )
            .take(1)) // take first response; discard others
    ... // continue processing result of the task
    .subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `Observable.amb` operator. It has the benefit of working with Observables with more than one emission.

Comment: Thanks will check it out .

Answer (score -1):

Below is the sample working code using RxJava Observables which prints the result from the fastest responding thread from a group of threads.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Create a slow thread which spans 5 secs
            Callable<String> task1 = new Callable<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            return "task1";
                    }
            };
            // Create a faster thread which spans 1 secs
            Callable<String> task2 = new Callable<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            return "task2";
                    }
            };
            List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            tasks.add(task1);
            tasks.add(task2);

            String result = null;
            try {
                    result =  Observable.from(tasks)
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                                    .flatMap(eachTask -> Observable.fromCallable(eachTask)
                                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                    .doOnNext(e -> System.out.println("Executing your action on "+Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                                                    .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Failed reason for : "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" with error "+e.getMessage()))
                                                    )
                                    .toBlocking()
                                    .first();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("result--->"+result);
}
```

Comment: bad suggestion, this wait for ALL of them to complete and THEN take the first one.

Comment: @DanieleSegato nope , if you could execute the code as it is you would see that it DOES NOT wait for ALL of them to complete. It picks the FIRST item returned by the BlockingObservable.

Comment: regardless, the request calls for merge + take(1) or merge + first()